# Laravel controller merge collections in one return

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I have 2 queries to return data from DB by Laravel controller
first :

```
$results = DB::table('transaction_sell_lines as tsl')
        ->select(DB::raw('b.name as results_business_location_name , t.location_id as results_location_id , tsl.product_id as results_product_id , p.name as results_product_name , tsl.variation_id as results_variation_id , sum(tsl.quantity) AS results_quantity , sum(tsl.quantity * tsl.unit_price_inc_tax) AS results_total'))
        ->leftjoin('transactions as t','t.id', '=', 'tsl.transaction_id')
        ->leftjoin('business_locations as b','b.id', '=', 't.location_id')
        ->leftjoin('products as p','p.id', '=', 'tsl.product_id')
        ->whereBetween('t.transaction_date',[$startDate.' 00:00:00', $endDate.' 23:59:59'])
        ->where('b.custom_field1', $location_type)
        ->where('t.type', '=' , 'sell')
        ->where('t.status', '=' , 'final')
        ->where('p.id', '!=' , 1)
        ->groupBy('tsl.variation_id')
        ->orderBy('tsl.variation_id', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

it will return result like

```
  #items: array:2 [▼
0 => { ▼
  +"results_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results_location_id": 18
  +"results_product_id": 513
  +"results_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results_variation_id": 661
  +"results_quantity": "211.0000"
  +"results_total": "4220.00000000"
}
1 => { ▼
  +"results_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results_location_id": 19
  +"results_product_id": 513
  +"results_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results_variation_id": 661
  +"results_quantity": "211.0000"
  +"results_total": "4220.00000000"
}
```

]
and second query is :

```
$results2 = DB::table('transaction_sell_lines as tsl')
        ->select(DB::raw('b.name as results2_business_location_name , t.location_id as results2_location_id , tsl.product_id as results2_product_id , p.name as results2_product_name , tsl.variation_id as results2_variation_id , sum(tsl.quantity) AS results2_quantity , sum(tsl.quantity * tsl.unit_price_inc_tax) AS results2_total'))
        ->leftjoin('transactions as t','t.id', '=', 'tsl.transaction_id')
        ->leftjoin('business_locations as b','b.id', '=', 't.location_id')
        ->leftjoin('products as p','p.id', '=', 'tsl.product_id')
        ->whereRaw("t.transaction_date LIKE '$reportdate%'")
        ->where('b.custom_field1', $location_type)
        ->where('t.type', '=' , 'sell')
        ->where('t.status', '=' , 'final')
        ->where('p.id', '!=' , 1)
        ->groupBy('tsl.variation_id')
        ->orderBy('tsl.variation_id', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('b.id', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

it will return result like

```
array:2 [▼
0 => { ▼
  +"results2_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results2_location_id": 18
  +"results2_product_id": 513
  +"results2_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results2_variation_id": 661
  +"results2_quantity": "1.0000"
  +"results2_total": "20.00000000"
}
1 => { ▼
  +"results2_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results2_location_id": 20
  +"results2_product_id": 513
  +"results2_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results2_variation_id": 661
  +"results2_quantity": "1.0000"
  +"results2_total": "20.00000000"
}
```

]

How can I merge between $results and $results2 to return only one collection ,
the marge must be to add object from $results2 to results which has same location_id and variation_id  , and if not find in $results , It will be added alone
example of needed collection

```
#items: array:4 [▼
0 => { ▼
  +"results_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results_location_id": 18
  +"results_product_id": 513
  +"results_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results_variation_id": 661
  +"results_quantity": "211.0000"
  +"results_total": "4220.00000000"
  +"results2_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results2_location_id": 18
  +"results2_product_id": 513
  +"results2_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results2_variation_id": 661
  +"results2_quantity": "1.0000"
  +"results2_total": "20.00000000"
}
1 => { ▼
  +"results_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results_location_id": 19
  +"results_product_id": 513
  +"results_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results_variation_id": 661
  +"results_quantity": "211.0000"
  +"results_total": "4220.00000000"
  +"results2_business_location_name": "0"
  +"results2_location_id": 0
  +"results2_product_id": 0
  +"results2_product_name": "0"
  +"results2_variation_id": 0
  +"results2_quantity": "0"
  +"results2_total": "0"
}
2 => { ▼
  +"results_business_location_name": "0"
  +"results_location_id": 0
  +"results_product_id": 0
  +"results_product_name": "0"
  +"results_variation_id": 0
  +"results_quantity": "0"
  +"results_total": "0"
  +"results2_business_location_name": "Video Game"
  +"results2_location_id": 20
  +"results2_product_id": 513
  +"results2_product_name": "موتوسيكل"
  +"results2_variation_id": 661
  +"results2_quantity": "1.0000"
  +"results2_total": "20.00000000"
}
```

]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not look like a collection. simple `array_merge` will work for this

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you by using array merge, example below:

```
array_merge($data1, $data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can merge two collection results by:

```
$first_collection  = collect(['Dog']);

$second_collection = collect(['Cat']);

$merged_collection = $first_collection->merge($second_collection);

dd($merged_collection->toArray());

// ['Dog', 'Cat']
```

UPDATE:

Apologies, maybe what you need is `push`.

Let's try:

```
$merged_collection = collect();

$first_collection  = collect(['Dog']);
    
$second_collection = collect(['Cat']);
    
$merged_collection->push($first_collection);
$merged_collection->push($second_collection);

OR

$first_collection->push($second_collection);
```

Comment: I tested it 
$collection = $results->merge($results2);
            dd($collection->toArray());
but it return $results data only

Comment: @fionka - can you please try the update?

Answer (score 0):

As in both quires you select the same columns, you can combine those quires into one which will return those results in one collection. You need to use `UNION` operator.

```
$first = DB::table('transaction_sell_lines as tsl')
    ->select(DB::raw('b.name as results_business_location_name , t.location_id as results_location_id , tsl.product_id as results_product_id , p.name as results_product_name , tsl.variation_id as results_variation_id , sum(tsl.quantity) AS results_quantity , sum(tsl.quantity * tsl.unit_price_inc_tax) AS results_total'))
    ->leftjoin('transactions as t','t.id', '=', 'tsl.transaction_id')
    ->leftjoin('business_locations as b','b.id', '=', 't.location_id')
    ->leftjoin('products as p','p.id', '=', 'tsl.product_id')
    ->whereBetween('t.transaction_date',[$startDate.' 00:00:00', $endDate.' 23:59:59'])
    ->where('b.custom_field1', $location_type)
    ->where('t.type', '=' , 'sell')
    ->where('t.status', '=' , 'final')
    ->where('p.id', '!=' , 1)
    ->groupBy('tsl.variation_id')
    ->orderBy('tsl.variation_id', 'asc');

$result = DB::table('transaction_sell_lines as tsl')
    ->select(DB::raw('b.name as results2_business_location_name , t.location_id as results2_location_id , tsl.product_id as results2_product_id , p.name as results2_product_name , tsl.variation_id as results2_variation_id , sum(tsl.quantity) AS results2_quantity , sum(tsl.quantity * tsl.unit_price_inc_tax) AS results2_total'))
    ->leftjoin('transactions as t','t.id', '=', 'tsl.transaction_id')
    ->leftjoin('business_locations as b','b.id', '=', 't.location_id')
    ->leftjoin('products as p','p.id', '=', 'tsl.product_id')
    ->whereRaw("t.transaction_date LIKE '$reportdate%'")
    ->where('b.custom_field1', $location_type)
    ->where('t.type', '=' , 'sell')
    ->where('t.status', '=' , 'final')
    ->where('p.id', '!=' , 1)
    ->groupBy('tsl.variation_id')
    ->orderBy('tsl.variation_id', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('b.id', 'asc')
    ->union($first)
    ->get();
```

you might need to modify this query, I haven't run it but should work.

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions)